# Unable to use bootstrap to a sample angular application

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have the following code, where I am trying to create a sample Angular Application and bootstrap it. However, the styles are not getting loaded properly.

`menubar.html`:

```html
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="display: inline">
        <div><a href="https://www.in28minutes.com" class="navbar-brand">in28Minutes</a></div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/welcome/shubham" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/todos" class="nav-link">Todos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
        <li><a href="/login" class="nav-link">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout" class="nav-link">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

`styles.css`:

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)
```

Here is how it renders:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried importing bootstrap CSS in `index.html` like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_bootstrap_link">` ?

Comment: I have tried adding it to index.html also but the page renders the same.

Comment: Check your internet connectivity. And also create a sample HTML page and try importing that bootstrap CSS and see if the problem exists.

Answer (score 2):

Your bootstrap has been loaded properly, as you can see in the screenshot that the font-family has changed to the bootstraps default font.

The mistake you might do is with HTML code and not with importing bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you , i got the issue . It was related to  style="display: inline" added to navbar class. Once i removed it , the styles started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to enable bootstrap to your angular project.

1. Including the Bootstrap CSS file in the `<head>` section of the `index.html` file of your Angular project with a `<link>` ,
2. Importing the Bootstrap CSS file in the global `styles.css` file of your Angular project with an `@import` keyword.
3. Adding the Bootstrap CSS file in the styles array of the `angular.json` file of your project.

The 3rd one is the most recommended way like,

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Comment: take carefull with the order, it's better put the last your "scr/styles.scss" to allow you override styles of bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

To use Bootstrap in an angular project, i recommend to import the css file in your angular.json like this

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

don't forget to install the npm module with "**npm i bootstrap**"

Comment: @shubham don't forget to install the npm module first, "npm i bootstrap"

Answer (score 1):

You can add bootstrap following this steps:

1. First install bootstrap from `npm` : `$ npm install bootstrap`.
   Then add bootstrap file location into `angular.json`

   ```
    "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     ],

    "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
     ],
   ```
2. Otherwise you can add cdn link of bootstrap in `index.html`

   ```
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>test</title>
   <base href="/">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

   </head>
   <body>

   <app-root></app-root>

   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
   ```